# Combining Bitwise And And Complement Operators

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

In the below code,since the bitwise complement of x is -1(using 2's Complement) and y is 2, I am expecting the value of z to be zero but I am getting the value of z as 2 when I run the program.Can anyone please explain me where I am going Wrong?

**CODE**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int x = 0, y = 2;
    int z = ~x & y;
    printf("%d\n", z);
}
```

Comment: In two's complement, -1 has that bit set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bitwise compliment of `0` is all `1`s so `AND`ing with it gives you exactly the other input to the `AND`, in this case `2`.

Assuming 8 bits to save space:

```
0    = 00000000
~0   = 11111111

2    = 00000010

~0&2 = 00000010
```

Comment: Is there no need to do 2's complement for zero because whenever we find the complement of a number say for example,we want to find the complement of 2,we get -3 right(Using 2's complement)?So,I was thinking in this case, since the bitwise complement of 0 is -1, we need to bitwise AND  -1 and 2?Is it wrong?

Comment: @SaiSankalp bitwise compliment has nothing to do with signed numbers and 2's complement, it's just a bitwise operation. 2's complement determines what bit pattern negative integers will have, so that addition with regular bit-operations will give the correct result.

Comment: Yeah I have gone through that.So I think I have cleared my doubt. So when we are doing bitwise And operation on a complement of a number with other number, it is enough to just flip the bits of that number and then proceed to bitwise And operation with other number right?

Comment: @SaiSankalp `~` means flip the bits